# How to make an android spinner that changes xml text?

Tags: android, eclipse, button, spinner, arabic

So im making an app that has Arabic in it
I want the user to be able to tap a spinner and have  a choice to select between "Transliteration and translation"
I want the Arabic text to stay the same but the English to change to what the user wants.
Thanks

Comment: Im just asking for some simple code that will a spinner that changes text in the xml

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to happen something when a user selects an item from a spinner, you have to set a OnItemSelectedListener to the spinner:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {...});
```

Comment: Look for the 'Hello Spinner' tutorial on developer.android.com